# Kibana - missing text highlighting for multi-field mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am experimenting with ECS - Elastic Common Schema.
We need to highlight text search for the field error.stack_trace . This field is a multi-field mapped defined [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/ecs/current/ecs-error.html#field-error-stack-trace)

I just did a simple test running Elasticsearch and Kibana 7.17.4 one field defined as multi-field and one with single field.

```
PUT simple-index-01
{
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "stack_trace01": { "type": "text" },
            "stack_trace02": {
              "fields": {
                "text": {
                  "type": "text"
                }
              },
              "type": "wildcard"
            }
          }
        }
}

POST simple-index-01/_doc 
{ 
  "@timestamp" : "2022-06-07T08:21:05.000Z", 
  "stack_trace01": "java.lang.NullPointerException: null",
  "stack_trace02": "java.lang.NullPointerException: null"
}
```

[image]

Is it a Kibana expected behavior not to highlight multi-fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wildcard` type will be not available to search using full text query as mentioned in documentaion (it is part of keyword type family):

> The `wildcard` field type is a specialized keyword field for
> unstructured machine-generated content you plan to search using
> grep-like `wildcard` and `regexp` queries.

So when you try below query it will not return result and this is the reason why it is not highlghting your `stack_trace02` field in discover.

```json
POST simple-index-01/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "stack_trace02": "null"
    }
  }
}
```

But below query will give result:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "stack_trace02": {
        "value": "*null*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can create index mapping something like below and your parent type field should `text` type:

```json
PUT simple-index-01
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "stack_trace01": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "stack_trace02": {
        "fields": {
          "text": {
            "type": "wildcard"
          }
        },
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

You can now use `stack_trace02.wildcard` when you want to search wildcard type of query.

There is already open [issue](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/118590) on similar behaviour but it is not for `wildcard` type.

Comment: Thank you and thank you for the link to the open issue. This behavior is somehow confusing. I think every developer in the whole wide world would want highlighting for the stack_trace field in discover.

Comment: @BjarteBrandt I am agree with your point.